# Trying to delete a column from a sharepoint document library view - SP2010

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to delete a field (site column bound to managed metadata) in a view with the following powershell script:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb -identity http://servernamehere/docs/test/sitename
$spView = $spWeb.GetListFromUrl("/EMails/Forms/AllItems.aspx")
$spField = $spView.Fields["Document Author"]
$spView.ViewFields.Delete($spField["Document Author"])
$spView.Update()
```

I get this error on line2:
v
Exception calling "GetListFromUrl" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot complete this action.

Please try again."
At line:1 char:32
+ $spView = $spWeb.GetListFromUrl <<<< ("/EMails/Forms/AllItems.aspx")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You have several mistakes here:

1. As djeeg mentioned, you need to use
   server relative url when calling
   GetListFromUrl, or (simplier) do not pass leading slash to GetListFromUrl,
   i.e. GetListFromUrl("Emails/Forms/AllItems.aspx"), I tested this code and it works for me.
2. You are using
   GetListFromUrl, which returns
   SPList, but you assign it to
   $spView. So probably
   you have a mistake here.
3. Fields
   indexer uses field internal name,
   which cannot contain white spaces,
   so you need to write smth like
   Fields["Document_x0020_Author"]
4. You don't need to fetch the SPField, you can use it's name to delete from ViewFields, for example, $spView.ViewFields.Delete("Document_x0020_Author")

Whole script will be:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb http://servernamehere/docs/test/sitename
$spList = $spWeb.GetListFromUrl("EMails/Forms/AllItems.aspx")
$spView = $spList.DefaultView
$spView.ViewFields.Delete("Document_x0020_Author")
$spView.Update()
```

This script worked for me without any errors.

Comment: +1 nice, i didn't look beyond the error message

Answer (score 2):

A third alternative is to use the new TryGetList() method in SP2010:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb http://servernamehere/docs/test/sitename$spList = $spWeb.GetListFromUrl("EMails/Forms/AllItems.aspx")
$list = $spWeb.Lists.TryGetList('my list title')
if ( $list )
{
    # do something intelligent here
}
```

This will get the list from title without any nullreference exceptions if the list isnt there.

More info [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistcollection.trygetlist.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`GetListFromUrl` says to use `GetListFromWebPartPageUrl`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlistfromurl.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlistfromwebpartpageurl.aspx

And the url probably needs to be server relative

```
SPList list = web.GetListFromWebPartPageUrl("/docs/test/sitename/EMails/Forms/AllItems.aspx");
```

Or have you tried `$spWeb.Lists["EMails"]`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms443550.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other webpart added to the AllItems.aspx page.. if so it will throw this error. can be checked by appending "?contents=1" to the url

btw..

- you can use "/EMails/Forms/AllItems.aspx" or "http://servernamehere/docs/test/sitename/EMails/Forms/AllItems.aspx" as parameter to GetListFromUrl
- you can use "Document Author", because 2010 accepts both displayname as well as internal name.. first it will try to resolve using internal name and then display name